# Layout file not using the correct dimen values file for Nexus 5X/6/6P emulators

Tags: android

I have a simple layout file with one `TextView` (for testing). I am attempting to change the size of the text based on the value of a `dimen` within the appropriate values file based on the device selected. **I can make this work for all devices available within Android Studio with the exception of Nexus 5X/6/6P**.

**Let's take the Nexus 6 as an example.**
1440 x 2560 - 560dpi
560dpi is an xxhdpi device (x3)
So dividing the resolution by 3 we get 480 x 853
The smallest width of this device being 480.

**I have values folders for the following:**
sw320dp
sw480dp
sw600dp
sw720dp
sw800dp

Actually, I have 5 of each of these, **one each for the densities of mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi.**

I have set the `textSize` property of my `TextView` in the layout to use the `dimen` of `myTextValue` which exists with different values in each of the different dimens files mentioned above.

When opening this layout file, it is showing that the values/dimen is being used and the value shows as 30, **which happens to be the value from my values-sw320dp-hdpi** folder.

Unless I am totally missing something, this is completely wrong. **It should be using the `dimen` from the values-sw480dp-xxhdpi folder.**

To complicate things even further, **even though I can tell which `dimen` file it used, making changes to that file does nothing to the layout, like it can't do anything with it / is not using it.**

This is only happening for the above 3 mentioned devices in Android Studio and is only happening with one of my 5 original layout files and any new files I create.  I have 4 other layout files which 'appear' to be working as I'd expect.

This is driving me crazy, so if anybody has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was an oversight on my part.  The three devices which 'seemed' to not be working correctly all were looking for a sw320dp-xxxhdpi values file and when one did not exist (my situation), it just used what matched best but then making changes to any of the other values files had no impact, which makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, something is still off here.  Take the most recent example.  I have been designing against the Nexus 10 in Android Studio all day via a dimens file that I have in values-sw800dp-xhdpi and things have been working perfectly.

Comment: As I made changes to the dimens file, the elements within my layout were updating and things were great.  This evening I went to go make a few more adjustments and my layout is now reading values from the first dimens file in the list.

Comment: But, even making changes to that file has no impact on my layout.  There seems to be little consistency here and I have been unable to determine what it is I am doing to cause things to stop working.  If anyone has any suggestions or thoughts on this, I woudl greatly appreciate it.  To confirm I am not overlooking something, I am using sw800dp-xhdpi because the Nexus 10 in AS is 2560 x 1600 / xhdpi so the smallest width would be 800 and density of xhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

From what i saw android uses the dimens found in the bigger folder that is smaller or equal to device dp resolution. So in fairness it just iterates from the biggest dimen folder that is smaller or equal the device dp resolution to the default folder from what i can tell there is no "matching" involved it uses thresholds which makes it very fast and very easy to predict which value will actually be used.

```
values | sw220dp | sw320dp | sw360dp | sw480dp | sw600dp | ...etc
.................................|device resolution DP
```

Screen resolution and size together with some other settings give the device a dp resolution ex 380 x 640 dp so this is smaller the 480 so first folder it checks is 360 -> towards default which is found first it is set. One more thing for the most part you can't control what dp resolution the device uses although there is a scaling setting that can be used to scale the layout and sp dimens used.

to find out device dp use this:

```
val width = resources.configuration.screenWidthDp
val height = resources.configuration.screenHeightDp
```